# why floor, ceil implementation return x + x when x is NaN or inf?

Tags: c, glibc, ieee-754, floor

I'm reading IEEE-754 math functions' implementation in glibc.
Here is `floor` implementation.

```
float
__floorf(float x)
{
    int32_t i0,j0;
    uint32_t i;
    GET_FLOAT_WORD(i0,x);
    j0 = ((i0>>23)&0xff)-0x7f;
    if(j0<23) {
        if(j0<0) {
        /* return 0*sign(x) if |x|<1 */
        if(i0>=0) {i0=0;}
        else if((i0&0x7fffffff)!=0)
          { i0=0xbf800000;}
        } else {
        i = (0x007fffff)>>j0;
        if((i0&i)==0) return x; /* x is integral */
        if(i0<0) i0 += (0x00800000)>>j0;
        i0 &= (~i);
        }
    } else {
        if(__builtin_expect(j0==0x80, 0)) return x+x; /* inf or NaN */
        else return x;      /* x is integral */
    }
    SET_FLOAT_WORD(x,i0);
    return x;
}
```

Interesting part is `if(__builtin_expect(j0==0x80, 0)) return x+x; /* inf or NaN */`.
Why does it return `x+x` when `x` is inf or NaN?
Why not just return `x`?

EDIT

I got my code from https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32/s_floorf.c and assumed it is fork from glibc.

Comment: The formatting of the code looks non-GNUish. Are you sure it's from glibc? You should [ask the author of that code](https://lists.debian.org/debian-glibc/2017/01/msg00016.html), whom I found by googling for `"float __floorf"`.

Comment: You should add to your question the links where you have searched for the answer. Knowing that this code came from SUN in 1993 might be helpful to finally answer the question.

Comment: Not very familiar with the standard, but IIRC NaNs can be signaling or not, and perhaps this is to handle that. Googling further from @RolandIllig's results, the [commit adding similar code](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=65cc568cf57156e5230db9a061645e54ff028a41) to glibc says: "The alpha version of floor wrongly return sNaN for sNaN input. Fix that
by checking for NaN and by returning the input value added with itself
in that case."

Comment: @muru: Yes, I think it's to set the FP exception flags, e.g. `ceil` needs to set or raise overflow on infinite inputs, or invalid on NaN inputs.

Comment: https://github.com/NetBSD/src/blame/c9ed02b28e7cedee7326c326f588496c93edd5f7/lib/libm/src/s_floor.c refers to fdlibm, whose history might be documented in some SCCS repository.

Comment: Yep, inf and NaN would emerge unchanged, but there are side effects that may be desired, at least for signalling NaNs: floating point exceptions.

Comment: Where is the official test suite for fdlibm or for IEEE 754 arithmetics? The answer is probably buried in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose is to raise exceptions. When the input to `floor` is a signaling NaN, the routine should raise the floating-point *invalid operation* exception.<sup>1</sup> Rather than calling some routine that would do this by manipulating bits in a floating-point status register, it is easier to simply evaluate `x+x`, as adding a signaling NaN to itself (or anything) will raise the *invalid operation* exception.

This is quite common in implementations of math library routines. For another example, consider `sin(x)`. For very small values of `x`, `sin(x)` is so near `x` that `x` is the closest value representable in the floating-point format, so the returned value should be `x`. But the exact mathematical sin *x* is not exactly `x` (if `x` is not zero), so the *inexact* exception should be raised. To do this, a routine may return, for example, `x + x*x`. When `x` is very small (but not zero), this will evaluate to the same as `x` but it will raise the *invalid* exception.

Note an added benefit in this case: When `x` is zero, `x + x*x` does not raise the *inexact* exception. Thus, the expression serves for both zero and very small non-zero cases. So it substitutes not only for manually raising an exception but also for branching based on whether `x` is zero or not. This is not uncommon in these expressions; they are an efficient way of implementing the function.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup>  Floating-point exceptions are not C++ exceptions. How they are handled depends on settings for the floating-point environment. Most commonly, they simply raise flags that the program can later check. But they can also cause traps that change program execution, like C++ exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I believe it has something to do with exception handling: if `x` is too large, then `return x+x` might generate an exception. While just `return x` would not cause any exception at all, and you might think that everything is ok, while in fact you're working with numbers which are wrong, either because they are beyond normal numbering range (`inf`), or because they simply are wrong (`NaN`).

Comment: NaN is not a number, so there's no range for it. Only inf is too large

Comment: @phuclv: you're right, I've adapted my answer accordingly.